# SSL Cert - Do I need to purchase SSL for a Domain that redirects to another Domain

Tags: ssl, dns

Quick dumb question but want to make sure. I need to redirect www.example.com to www.example1.com. www.example1.com is already secured with a SSL cert. Do i need to purchase a SSL cert for www.example.com? I am assuming 'No' because the redirect is landing on a page that is aready secured.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Alpha

Answer (score 2):

The ability to issue an HTTP-level redirect is *independent* of whether the original or destination sites are protected by HTTPS (SSL/TLS) and a corresponding certificate.  Redirects may be issued in any combination, specifically all of these are allowed:

```
FROM                      TO
http://www.example.com    http://www.other.example
http://www.example.com    https://www.other.example
https://www.example.com   http://www.other.example
https://www.example.com   https://www.other.example
```

Before any of these HTTP redirects to take place, the client must be able to establish a valid HTTP request with the "FROM" server.  If `www.example.com` is an Internet-accessible site intended to be used by anyone, *and* it uses HTTPS, then it *must* use a certificate; preferably, one signed by a recognized CA (Certificate Authority).  However, this concern is *not specific to the topic of redirects*; it would apply to *any* request to that server and should be treated as a *separate concern*.

The answer to my interpretation of the OP's question is: **No, the source of a redirect does not need to be secured with SSL/TLS merely in order to issue a redirect to a protected site.** (Case 2 in my table above.)

There may be other reasons why the originating server *should* use HTTPS, but it is not a requirement *merely* for the ability to redirect.  Note that in some cases (e.g. case 3) a browser may warn the user if redirecting to an *insecure* page from an HTTPS context.

Comment: Great! Thank you for verifing.

Comment: It does. If you want `https://www.example.com` (note `https://` here) to send its redirect to `https://www.example1.com`, a valid initial connection has to be possible to `www.example.com`, hence it needs a valid certificate.

Comment: Bruno, I respectfully disagree.  I think that confuses two issues: (1) how am I connecting to `www.example.com` and (2) does the originating site need to be using HTTPS in order to redirect to a different site that *is* using HTTPS.  I maintain that the OP's question and my answer are in respect to (2).  In your presumption of (1), if the originating site is using HTTPS then, yes, the need for a certificate is self explanatory.

Comment: I understood it as requiring an HTTPS connection first, which seems to be what the OP wants according to the latest comment on the other answer, but after re-reading the question, I agree it wasn't clear. Sorry about that. The votes are locked, but if you feel like editing your answer at some point, I'll change my vote.

Comment: @Bruno Clarified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect from https://www.example.com to https://www.example1.com you need a certificate for www.example.com too. The redirect will be done with HTTP, but https encapsulates HTTP inside SSL. So it first needs to establish the SSL connection which includes verifying the certificate, before it can get to the HTTP layer with the redirect.

Comment: Interesting to know. Thanks for your feedback. Looks like i need to figure out how to get a SSL for the source domain.

Comment: This presumes that `www.example.com` is hosting HTTPS already, in which case it would need a certificate regardless of any redirect behavior.  However, if `www.example.com` is merely serving plain HTTP then it is free to redirect to any destination it wishes.

Comment: yes that is correct. The domain that needs to be redirected is already a HTTPS. Is there a easy way to figure out who is hosting that URL...what field should i be looking for in whois record. The reason I ask is because i would need a CSR for the registrar to issue a SSL cert.

Comment: The technical contact is the right person - but if you own the domain already you should know where it is hosted. And if you don't own it you should not be able to get a certificate for this.