# Apache - Redirect non-subdomained https traffic to www

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

I have a signed wild card certificate for *.example.com. I am redirecting all non-https traffic to https with my VirtualHosts config.

My problem though is that the certificate is only for subdomains so if a user goes to http**s**://example.com (no subdomain) then the certificate is invalid and won't follow the redirect to the page with the valid certificate without the big scary warning.

My configuration at the moment is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com

        SSLEngine ON
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/certs/cert.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/key.pem

        Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: see this: http://serverfault.com/questions/429274/how-to-redirect-from-https-to-http-before-server-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL Cert - Do I need to purchase SSL for a Domain that redirects to another Domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746049/ssl-cert-do-i-need-to-purchase-ssl-for-a-domain-that-redirects-to-another-doma)